# Mu ubuntu stuck at installing vmware tools. please wait

Tags: installation, vmware

I have installed Ubuntu desktop on vmware player 5.0.2 on windows 7 64bit os. after installing vmware tools on the desktop it always stops and giving  installing vmware tools. please wait. its a continuous process and not showing gui or command line either. . Any help  will be appriciated..I can not upload images here...

Answer (score 1):

Startup the Ubuntu guest without installing vmware-tools. You should now see the standard Unity desktop.

If you don't have it push Ctrl+Alt+F1 to get to tty1 and after updating and installing build-essential and linux-headers-$(uname -r) continue with option 1) or 2), you don't have to open a terminal, just type the commands.

First, you need to update and upgrade and install build-essential and the latest linux-headers in the Ubuntu guest, in your case Ubuntu-13.04. Do it by running the following in a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+t opens the terminal):

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get upgrade`

`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

This upgrades Ubuntu to the latest packages and the latest regular kernel.

When prompted for a password, enter your Ubuntu admin user password.

Note: For security reasons, the typed password is not displayed. You do not need to enter your password again for the next five minutes.

`sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

Now try installing vmware-tools regularly.

If this doesn't work there are two options:

1) Install vmware-tools via command line:

In the Ubuntu guest, run these commands (In the terminal):

`sudo mkdir /mnt/cdrom`

`sudo mount /dev/cdrom /mnt/cdrom` or `sudo mount /dev/sr0 /mnt/cdrom`

The file name of the VMware Tools bundle varies depending on your version of the VMware product. Run this command to find the exact name:

`ls /mnt/cdrom`

`tar xzvf /mnt/cdrom/VMwareTools-x.x.x-xxxx.tar.gz -C /tmp/`

Note: x.x.x-xxxx is the version discovered in the previous step.

`cd /tmp/vmware-tools-distrib/`and now`sudo ./vmware-install.pl -d`

Note: The -d switch assumes that you want to accept the defaults. If you do not use -d, press Return to accept each default or supply your own answers.

Run this command to reboot the virtual machine after the installation completes:

`sudo reboot`

After reboot vmware-tools should be working.

2) The Open Virtual Machine Tools (open-vm-tools) are the open source implementation of VMware Tools. They are a set of guest operating system virtualization components that enhance performance and user experience of virtual machines.

Install open-vm-tools:

`sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools open-vm-dkms open-vm-toolkit`

`sudo reboot`

After reboot open-vm-tools should be working.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 13.04 will be outdated in 20 days, please update to the latest version and also update VMware player as it is free and the most updated version will fix many issues as well as giving you a much better performance:

[Latest VMware player](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_player/6_0)

[Ubuntu 13.10 32 bits](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?release=latest&bits=32&distro=desktop&status=zeroc)