# Ubuntu VM fails to boot and blocks at "installing open-vm-tools"

Tags: boot, 20.04, vmware-workstation

I have created a VM with ubuntu 20.04.1 on VMware Workstation 12.5.
When starting the VM it gets blocked at `installing open-vm-tools`
I have the network connected and I can open a Fedora VM which is working fine.
BTW I have also some fails about cpufreq related to the cores.

Here a screenshot of the errors:
[image: ubuntu 20.04.1 fails to boot]

Any idea?

Comment: See if this helps: https://askubuntu.com/questions/330538/mu-ubuntu-stuck-at-installing-vmware-tools-please-wait

Answer (score 1):

Same problem, I solved removing SCSI disk and creating a new one in SATA mode.